# What's the effect of cache to NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, macos, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I read the doc of course, but I don't quite get the meaning of "setting up any sections and ordering the contents".

1. Don't these kinds of information come form data base?
2. Does it mean `NSFetchedResultsController` needs some other kinds of indices itself beside data base indices?
3. What's really going on when `NSFetchedResultsController` is setting up a cache?
4. Is cache useful for static data only? If my data update frequently, should I use cache or not?
5. How can I profile the performance of cache? I tried cache, but couldn't see any performance improvement. I timed `-performFetch:` but saw a time increase from 0.018s(without cache) to 0.023s(with cache). I also timed `-objectAtIndexPath:` and only a time decrease from 0.000030(without cache) to 0.000029(with catch).

In other words, I want to know when cache does(or does not) improves performance and why.

As @Marcus pointed below, "500 Entries is tiny. Core Data can handle that without a human noticeable lag. Caching is used when you have tens of thousands of records." So I think there are few apps that would benefit from using cache.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The cache for the `NSFetchedResultsController` is a kind of short cut.  It is a cache of the last results from the `NSFetchRequest`.  It is not the entire data but enough data for the `NSFetchedResultsController` to display its results quickly; very quickly.

It is a "copy" of the data from the database that is serialized to disk in a format that is easily consumed by the `NSFetchedResultsController` on its next instantiation.

To look at it another way, it is the last results flash frozen to disk.

Comment: Thanks, @Marcus. If my data update frequently, should I use cache or not?

Comment: I would use the cache unless you are going to change the predicate often.

Comment: I tried cache, but couldn't see any performance improvement. How can I profile the performance of cache? I timed -performFetch: but saw a time increase from 0.018s(without cache) to 0.023s(with cache). I also timed -objectAtIndexPath: and only a time decrease from 0.000030(without cache) to 0.000029(with catch).

Comment: The cache will only improve performance on a second launch (first launch you are building the cache). Also the benefit of the cache is only going to be felt if your fetch without it is taking a human noticeable amount of time.  Your current data set is too small to receive an improvement.  Try loading up a test with an order of magnitude more data then you expect the app to hold then watch the performance.

Comment: My profiling didn't take the initial run into account. I don't think my data base is small — I have about 500 entries. If it really require more than thousands of entries for cache to show its effect, cache is probably not fit for my use case and I doubt there are many apps that would benefit from using cache. However I suspect maybe it is because cache just does not help much for single-section data and my list has only one section. But I don't have a multi-section list to test so I can't tell.

Comment: 500 Entries is *tiny*.  Core Data can handle that without a human noticeable lag.  Caching is used when you have *tens of thousands* of records.  Looking for optimizations is something you do **after** you find a hotspot, otherwise it is wasted effort.

Comment: I did profiling because my launch time is not good. Thanks anyway.

Comment: if you are seeing a retrieval time in 1/100th of a second time then it is not Core Data :)

Comment: Altough this question is already been toroughly answered, I would like to add that, beside performance, a fetch controller become really useful when you are dealing with row inserting,deleting and updating.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) of `NSFetchedResultsController`:

> Where possible, a controller uses a cache to avoid the need to repeat work performed in setting up any ***sections*** and ***ordering*** the contents

To take advantage of the cache you should use sectioning or ordering of your data.

So if in `initWithFetchRequest:managedObjectContext:sectionNameKeyPath:cacheName:` you set the `sectionNameKeyPath` to `nil` you probably won't notice any performance gain.

Answer (score 0):

[From the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontroller#1661453)

> The Cache Where possible, a controller uses a cache to avoid the need
>   to repeat work performed in setting up any sections and ordering the
>   contents. The cache is maintained across launches of your application.
>
> When you initialize an instance of NSFetchedResultsController, you
>   typically specify a cache name. (If you do not specify a cache name,
>   the controller does not cache data.) When you create a controller, it
>   looks for an existing cache with the given name:
>
> If the controller can’t find an appropriate cache, it calculates the
>   required sections and the order of objects within sections. It then
>   writes this information to disk.
>
> If it finds a cache with the same name, the controller tests the cache
>   to determine whether its contents are still valid. The controller
>   compares the current entity name, entity version hash, sort
>   descriptors, and section key-path with those stored in the cache, as
>   well as the modification date of the cached information file and the
>   persistent store file.
>
> If the cache is consistent with the current information, the
>   controller reuses the previously-computed information.
>
> If the cache is not consistent with the current information, then the
>   required information is recomputed, and the cache updated.
>
> Any time the section and ordering information change, the cache is
>   updated.
>
> If you have multiple fetched results controllers with different
>   configurations (different sort descriptors and so on), you must give
>   each a different cache name.
>
> You can purge a cache using deleteCache(withName:).